# customize UIPickerView elements to start at top in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipickerview

1.--> I need to customize a UIPickerview elements to start from the top.As of now we can see the picker elements starting from the middle like the one shown in figure(apple started from middle of picker) but not from the top...
Is there a way to do it?How can I do it ?

[image]

2.--> How can I make a PickerView Start At A Certain Row When It Is First Displayed
      I knew this code:

```
  [self.view addSubview:aPicker];
  [aPicker selectRow:14 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

But I have  a textfield and I want the textfield text (eg: California) which is also one of the element of pickerView ,but its row position is not known to be displayed as the default value of UIPickerView..How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure what you mean here. Do you want the selection indicator to be at the top, and for that to be where the picker stops when you spin it? If so, I think that would be a hard thing to do.

2) To have the picker start at a particular row, just get the index of that item in the data source array, and select the picker row based on that. Something like this could be used as the text field's action method:

```
-(IBAction)startPickerAtText:(UITextField *) sender {
    NSInteger indx = [self.theData indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:sender.text];
    if (indx != NSNotFound) {
        [self.picker selectRow:indx inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: 1-->What I mean is generally we see picker starting from the center and first elemnt to be selected as default.So what I need is the picker's elements to start from top ..Is it possible?

Comment: @Sindhia, sorry, I still don't understand. What do you mean by top? Are you talking about the physical look of the picker or the data? Do you want the selection spot to be at the top of the picker rather than the middle? An example might help me understand.

Comment: I know what a picker looks like, that didn't really answer my question, so I'll try one more time. Do you want the selection indicator (the blue bar) to be at the top of the picker? Yes or no? If so, I don't think there's any way to do that, other than by making your own picker from scratch. Why do you want that look?

Comment: I think you could add you own view and make it look like the selection bar (which you can hide so it won't appear). The main difficulty I see is getting the wheels to stop at the right place, so it would look like the titles are centered on your custom selection view

Comment: @Sindhia, you mean you don't want the blank space at the top when the picker first appears (like above Apple in your picture)?

Comment: @Sindhia, Then you need to select the second or third row at start up to move the wheels up.

Comment: But what if I want first row to be at start up ?

Comment: @Sindhia, look, I can't write your code for you. I told you how to move the selection bar to the top. If you do that, and move the rows up one or two, you can return a value from your array that is offset from the actual selection (which will still be in the middle) so that it will appear that the selection is at the top and on the first row of data.