# How to customize an UIPickerView in iPhone Xcode reducing its dimension?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, uipickerview

I would like to reduce the height of a UIPickerView in my iPhone app, so that it shows only 4 rows on the right side of a label. It's a sign up view. I want just a little pickerview for the credit card type. Can anyone help me? How can I do it ? I usually use the storyboard for my apps

If it's not possible, how can I do something like this?
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775106/customize-uipickerview-elements-to-start-at-top-in-xcode)

Something like a UITextField that becomes a Picker at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can shrink your picker view by using affine transform

```
pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);
```

this will scale a picker to 75% of its original size

and just do this in the UITextField delegate textFieldShouldReturn method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField == yourTextField)
    {
        [self callYourPicker];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

show your pickerView in action sheet see this link http://www.sortedbits.com/putting-a-uipickerview-on-a-uiactionsheet/